# Making a Bitmap from previously extracted Bitmapbits?

Tags: python, winapi, bitmap, ctypes, pywin32

I'm trying to work out how to "rebuild" a bitmap after extracting the `BitmapBits` from the object.

I'm rewriting a small application so that I can take advantage of the available cores in my machine. Because I'm using Python, before I can send anything to another process, that object must first be serialized via `Pickling`. The only part of the PyCBitmap objects that *are* picklable are the bytestrings that get returned from `GetBitmapBits`. Thus the only way to leverage the additional processors is to extract the bytestring from the bitmap, pickle it, and then rebuild it on the other side.

However, the issue I've run into is that I'm not sure how to make a new bitmap object from the extracted bytestring. There is a `CreateBitmap` method in the `win32gui` library. However, [from the docs](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.3/pywin32/win32gui__CreateBitmap_meth.html) the `bitmapbits` parameter *must* be set to `None`. So that's out.

Does anyone know how to create a new bitmap object from a bytestring?

Comment: @eryksun After a bit of trial and error, I was able to create the bitmap via ctypes. However, the only problem is that ctypes isn't compatible with pywin32's types. So I can't so something like `SelectObject` on the `pywin32` side and pass in the int handle. I haven't found a way to wrap the handle up as a PyGdiHandle to see if that works.

Comment: Maybe create the bitmap using pywin32, get the handle, and then use ctypes to call [`SetBitmapBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162962).

Comment: @eryksun Ah, man! Clever! That worked. Thanks a bunch! If you want to submit it as the answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Feel free to write your solution up as an answer to your own question. Look into using a [`sharedctypes.RawArray`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing.sharedctypes) as an alternative to pickling and piping the data to the child process.